# put buttons in relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have buttons that stick to the bottom of the layout.I want to add them to a layout and put a background to them. How can I achieve this? I tried a lot but i cant.

```
<RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <in.wptrafficanalyzer.graphicspickimageviewcanvas.PaintView
                android:id="@+id/paint_view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/btn_pick"  />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_pick"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:text="pick"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/save"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:text="save"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_pick"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_pick"
                android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="45dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try to delete android:layout_above="@+id/btn_pick"

Comment: @JCodex if i delet my costume view gets over buttons.

Comment: Question is not clear, i thought that custom view is your background

Comment: if you want that customview to be in background, try putting customview after buttons in xml. That may do trick

Comment: Are you saying that you want a separate background in the relative layout? If so, what exactly happens when you try. The question is very hard to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <in.wptrafficanalyzer.graphicspickimageviewcanvas.PaintView
            android:id="@+id/paint_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/buttonWrapper"  />

      <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/buttonWrapper"
           android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:background="@color/yourcolor"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_pick"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="pick"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="45dp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="save"
            android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="45dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

just supply something for yourcolor in colors.xml

Answer (score 0):

They're sticked to the bottom for this

```
        <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <in.wptrafficanalyzer.graphicspickimageviewcanvas.PaintView
            android:id="@+id/paint_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btn_pick"  />
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#25348C"                 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_pick"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:text="pick"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:text="save"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_pick"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_pick"
            android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="45dp" />
       </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I understand that you don't wat that, so delete that line, if that's not the answer could you please post a picture (mockup) of both, the layout you have and the one you want, so we can help you with that.

EDIT:
android:background="#25348C" <---- any color you want (@color/colorName it's better and place the color resource at an xml resource file)

Comment: i know why they sticks.i want to stick at bottom.i just want to add this two button to a relative layout to set a background.